# ANTLR semantic predicate - doesn't block rule

Tags: python, antlr, grammar, predicate

I'm having some trouble with a semantic predicate on an ANTLR parser rule.  Here's my grammar, intended to recognize a couple different date formats:

```
grammar sample ;

options { language=Python3; }

@parser::header {
from datetime import datetime
}

month_number returns [val] : INTEGER { 1    <= int($INTEGER.text) <= 12   }?  {$val = int($INTEGER.text)} ;
day_number   returns [val] : INTEGER { 1    <= int($INTEGER.text) <= 31   }?  {$val = int($INTEGER.text)} ;
year_4digit  returns [val] : INTEGER { 1900 <= int($INTEGER.text) <= 2100 }?  {$val = int($INTEGER.text)} ;

year_2digit  returns [val] : '\''? INTEGER {(int($INTEGER.text) >= 65 or int($INTEGER.text) < 40)}?
                                     {$val = (1900 + int($INTEGER.text)) if (int($INTEGER.text) >= 65) else (2000 + int($INTEGER.text))} ;

year_digits  returns [val]
  : year_4digit {$val = $year_4digit.val}
  | year_2digit {$val = $year_2digit.val}
  ;


mdy returns [val]
  : month_number '-' day_number '-' year_digits  {$val = datetime($year_digits.val, $month_number.val, $day_number.val)}
  | month_number '/' day_number '/' year_digits  {$val = datetime($year_digits.val, $month_number.val, $day_number.val)}
  ;

ymd returns [val]
  : year_4digit '-' month_number '-' day_number  {$val = datetime($year_4digit.val, $month_number.val, $day_number.val)}
  | year_4digit '/' month_number '/' day_number  {$val = datetime($year_4digit.val, $month_number.val, $day_number.val)}
  ;

date_as_numbers returns [val]
  : ymd {$val = $ymd.val}
  | mdy {$val = $mdy.val}
  ;

INTEGER: '0'..'9'+ ;
```

I test that with the following program:

```
from myPackage.sampleParser import sampleParser
from myPackage.sampleLexer import sampleLexer

from antlr4 import CommonTokenStream
from antlr4 import InputStream

date_input = InputStream("2/12/2017".lower())
lexer = sampleLexer(date_input)
stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
parser = sampleParser(stream)
result = parser.date_as_numbers()
print(result.val)
```

This results in the following error:

```
line 1:1 rule year_4digit failed predicate: { 1900 <= int($INTEGER.text) <= 2100 }?
line 1:9 rule day_number failed predicate: { 1    <= int($INTEGER.text) <= 31   }?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kwilliams/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2017.3/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 11, in <module>
    result = parser.date_as_numbers()
  File "/Users/kwilliams/git/myPackage/sampleParser.py", line 482, in date_as_numbers
    localctx._ymd = self.ymd()
  File "/Users/kwilliams/git/myPackage/sampleParser.py", line 436, in ymd
    localctx.val = datetime(localctx._year_4digit.val, localctx._month_number.val, localctx._day_number.val)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)
```

So what I believe is happening is that the predicate in `year_4digit` throws an exception because the number `2` isn't in its range, but it returns a `year_4digit` match anyway, which hasn't had its `val` attribute populated, causing a downstream error about `NoneType`.  Is that correct?

If so - what's a good solution?  Do I need to put the semantic predicates earlier in the rules or something?  How would I do a lookahead to the `INTEGER` token if that's the right solution?

(Also - I expected to be able to do `$INTEGER.int` instead of `int($INTEGER.text)`, but maybe that's not available in the Python target?  Tangential and minor issue.)

BTW, the above grammar is a smallish excerpt from my real grammar, I'm hoping that there's a solution that doesn't require major changes to this part, potentially causing ripple effects that might take a while to sort out.

Thanks.

Comment: I fixed my example, I was mistakenly calling `ymd` directly instead of the `date_as_numbers` rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the predicates are nested too deep causing the parser not to backtrack and try the second alternative:

```antlr
date_as_numbers returns [val]
  : ymd {$val = $ymd.val} // alternaitve 1
  | mdy {$val = $mdy.val} // alternaitve 2
  ;
```

When I swap the alternatives:

```antlr
date_as_numbers returns [val]
  : mdy {$val = $mdy.val}
  | ymd {$val = $ymd.val}
  ;
```

the input `"2/12/2017"` is parsed correctly, but then `"2017/12/2"` fails.

I don't know if this is expected behaviour, or a bug (I've never done much with the new v4 predicates yet). You could [raise an issue](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues) about this.

After playing around a bit, I've got something working by merging the rules into 1 big `any_date` rule, and letting these rules start with the predicate rather than having a predicate somewhere in the middle (as you yourself already hinted about):

```antlr
grammar sample;

@parser::members {
  boolean lte(Token token, int value) {
    return Integer.parseInt(token.getText()) <= value;
  }
  boolean gte(Token token, int value) {
    return Integer.parseInt(token.getText()) >= value;
  }
}

date_as_numbers returns [String val]
  : any_date EOF {$val = $any_date.val;}
  ;

any_date returns [String val]
 : {gte(_input.LT(1), 1) && lte(_input.LT(1), 12)}?
   INTEGER '-' day_number '-' year_digits {$val = "y=" + $year_digits.val + ", m=" + $INTEGER.text + ", d=" + $day_number.val;}
 | {gte(_input.LT(1), 1) && lte(_input.LT(1), 12)}?
   INTEGER '/' day_number '/' year_digits {$val = "y=" + $year_digits.val + ", m=" + $INTEGER.text + ", d=" + $day_number.val;}
 | {gte(_input.LT(1), 1900) && lte(_input.LT(1), 2100)}?
   INTEGER '-' month_number '-' day_number {$val = "y=" + $INTEGER.text + ", m=" + $month_number.val + ", d=" + $day_number.val;}
 | {gte(_input.LT(1), 1900) && lte(_input.LT(1), 2100)}?
   INTEGER '/' month_number '/' day_number {$val = "y=" + $INTEGER.text + ", m=" + $month_number.val + ", d=" + $day_number.val;}
 ;

month_number returns [int val]
 : INTEGER {gte($INTEGER, 1) && lte($INTEGER, 12)}?
   {$val = Integer.parseInt($INTEGER.text);}
 ;

day_number returns [int val]
 : INTEGER {gte($INTEGER, 1) && lte($INTEGER, 31)}?
   {$val = Integer.parseInt($INTEGER.text);}
 ;

year_4digit returns [int val]
 : INTEGER {gte($INTEGER, 1900) && lte($INTEGER, 2100)}?
   {$val = Integer.parseInt($INTEGER.text);}
 ;

year_2digit returns [int val]
 : '\''? INTEGER {gte($INTEGER, 65) || lte($INTEGER, 39)}?
   {$val = Integer.parseInt($INTEGER.text) >= 65 ? 1900 + Integer.parseInt($INTEGER.text) : 2000 + Integer.parseInt($INTEGER.text);}
 ;

year_digits  returns [int val]
  : year_4digit {$val = $year_4digit.val;}
  | year_2digit {$val = $year_2digit.val;}
  ;

INTEGER: '0'..'9'+ ;
```

*(sorry, no python)*

When running this class:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] tests = { "2/12/2017", "2017/12/31", "1-2-'03" };

    for (String test : tests) {
      sampleLexer lexer = new sampleLexer(CharStreams.fromString(test));
      sampleParser parser = new sampleParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
      System.out.println(test + " -> " + parser.date_as_numbers().val);
    }
  }
}
```

the following is printed:

```
2/12/2017 -> y=2017, m=2, d=12
2017/12/31 -> y=2017, m=12, d=31
1-2-'03 -> y=2003, m=1, d=2
```

I know, not perfect, but perhaps you can tweak your current grammar a bit and get something working.

### EDIT

Of course, you could also ditch the predicates and do something like this instead:

```antlr
grammar sample;

date_as_numbers
 : ymd
 | mdy
 | failure
 ;

ymd
 : year '/' month '/' day
 | year '-' month '-' day
 ;

mdy
 : month '/' day '/' year
 | month '-' day '-' year
 ;

year
 : '\''? year_2digits
 | NUM_4DIGITS
 ;

year_2digits
 : NUM_1_12
 | NUM_13_31
 | NUM_2DIGITS
 ;

month
 : NUM_1_12
 ;

day
 : NUM_1_12
 | NUM_13_31
 ;

failure
 : NUM_OTHER
 ;

NUM_1_12
 : [1-9]     // 1..9
 | '1' [0-2] // 10..12
 ;

NUM_13_31
 : '1' [3-9] // 13..19
 | '2' D     // 20..29
 | '3' [01]  // 30..31
 ;

NUM_2DIGITS
 : D D
 ;

NUM_4DIGITS
 : '19' D D // 1900..1999
 | '20' D D // 2000..2099
 | '2100'   // 2100
 ;

NUM_OTHER
 : D+
 ;

fragment D : [0-9];
```

Comment: Thanks.  This kind of makes me wonder what the point of semantic predicates is, if it doesn't actually change the parsing path.  Or is this only happening because the predicate is at the very end of a production alternative?

Comment: No problem. Not sure what you mean by "if it doesn't actually change the parsing path". In your case, it changes the path in such a way that the rule `ymd` isn't recognised (if you're not using ANTLR's bult-in error recovery). And no, the location doesn't matter. I assume you've already read the official docs about predicates, but in case you've missed it, have a look here: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/predicates.md

Comment: I just realized that I had an error in demonstrating my problem - I didn't mean to call the `ymd` rule directly, I meant to call the `date_as_numbers` rule and let it figure out that it matches the `mdy` alternative, not `ymd` (since it fails a semantic predicate in the `ymd` case).  I'll update my example.

Comment: @KenWilliams check my revised answer. – Bart Kiers 25 mins ago

Comment: Thanks Bart, extremely helpful.  I'll play around with the ideas here to see whether I can get them to fit in my larger grammar.  I like the `NUM_1_12`, `NUM_13_31` etc. idea, I considered it myself too, but a wrinkle is that there are more range divisions than just these ones I've shown here, and sometimes I want to allow a leading zero, sometimes I don't, so it blows up the combinatorics a bit.